# Creation of my NFC APP

Tags: android, tags, nfc

> Hi Everyone, i developed an NFC app and installed it over to my NEXUS S phone.. but on showing the tag the app didn't load?? may i no y?? and how shall i over come it..
>
> my problem is that when the nexus discoveres a tag, my app is not listed in the "select an action"-popup.

```
public class TagReader extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            msgs[0] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
        }
        NdefRecord[] record = msgs[0].getRecords();
        Preconditions.checkArgument(record[0].getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(Arrays.equals(record[0].getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT));
        byte[] bRecord = record[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((bRecord[0] & 0200) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
        int languageCodeLength = bRecord[0] & 0077;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        content.removeAllViews();
        try{
            String languageCode = new String(bRecord, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");
            String text = new String(bRecord, languageCodeLength + 1,bRecord.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
            TextView textv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_text, content, false);
            textv.setText(text);
            content.addView(textv);
            String x = null;
        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.nfc.TagReader"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".TagReader"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

> Kindly reply as soon as possible please am really stuck..

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you are missing the intent filters that are to be associated with the activity concerned.

Add the following piece of xml in AndroidManifest.xml under your main launcher class

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Also note that you would need the nfc_tech_filter.xml file under res/xml that specifies the tech-list.

Hope that helps !!